# Form not posting data unless I specify index.php

Tags: html, forms, post

I have a form which has an action of `/register` but data is not getting posted to this.

However, if I change the action to `/register/index.php` it posts to the same page and works fine.

I'd ideally like to keep my URLs looking as clean as possible so is there a way to make the first example work?

Here's the form:

```
<form method="post" id="login" action="/register">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
</form>
```

Here's the contents of my htaccess file if that might have anything to do with it...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: Do you use `POST` or `GET`? Or anything helpful to look for problems?

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili - I've added the code though it's really not all that complicated. Changing the action to /register/index.php make it work fine!

Comment: are you sure in both case it's requesting the same file? I mean if there is any url redirection, or index.html may have much precedences when omitting the index file name

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili - I've added my htaccess file content for you to look at but I can't see why that would be a problem.

Comment: Do you perhaps have an `index.php` and an `index.html` file within the `/register` directory?

Comment: No. As I said, it goes to the correct page, it just doesn't post the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in the path.

You can't use `/register`, because `register` isn't a file and it isn't a path too.

Using `/register/` would be equal to `/register/index.php`.

So if you're using `/register/` or `/register/index.php`, it will point to the index file you're using.

Keep in mind that I'm using the following settings in the Apache conf file:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
   DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

Also, I'm assuming you don't have an "index.html" file in that directory. Otherwise, according to the settings stated above, `\register\` will point to the `index.html` file instead of `index.php`.